# Auto stretch a list element with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've got a `ul` element with a variable number of `li` elements. I want the last `li` element to always fill the remaining space on the first line, or, if there's less than a predefined minimum, I'd like it to move to a new line.

Diagrams to demonstrate:

[image]

I've tried this with various combinations of float left, float right, display block, inline, inline-block, table, min-width etc. I can't make it work. I'm willing to do down the javascript route if necessary but first I wanted to see if anyone can figure it out in pure CSS for me

Comment: Do you hav some code?

Comment: Have the other ones before the last one a fixed width?

Comment: You need to update your graphic as they're all ULs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use some nifty CSS- namely remove the default styling for your list and list items, then float each `li` left except the last one- which you apply `overflow:hidden;` to to force it to take up the remaining space. By giving it a `min-width` you also specify it should move to a newline after a certain point.

nb. You'll want to change the `200px` to `250px`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MANJ6/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul, li{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:10px;
}
li{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100px;
}
li:last-child{
    float:none;/* <--- stop the last item from being floated */
    width:auto;/* <--- make the last item have an automatic width */
    overflow:hidden;/* <--- force it to take up the remaining space */
    min-width:200px; /* <--- except if the remaining space is less than 200px, in which case move it to a new line */
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, but just to note this won't work on older browsers.

Comment: it seems so simple now! @MatthewT.Baker can you explain which part won't work? I'm guessing the :last-child...

Comment: `:last-child` is not supported by IE8 or below.  Check out http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/ for compatibility information.

Comment: +1 You can always apply a class to the last child instead to extend compatibility